# SQL equivalent queries in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm converting my SQL queries into MongoDB. I have the following SQL statement which checks an input and perform the query accordingly.

```
(score_min = -1 OR Scores BETWEEN score_min AND score_max)
```

Scores is a field name, which I want to filter
Still couldn't figure out the best way to perform this query in a MongoDB aggregate pipeline. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the behaviour with a `$expr` in a simple `find`. Not a must to use aggregation pipeline.

```js
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $or: [
      {
        // $eq: [<score_min>, -1]
        $eq: [
          <score_min>,
          -1
        ]
      },
      {
        $and: [
          {
            // $gte: ["$Scores", <score_min>]
            $gte: [
              "$Scores",
              <score_min>
            ]
          },
          {
            $lte: [
              // $gte: ["$Scores", <score_max>]
              "$Scores",
              <score_max>
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3UkfsU_j7xE) for your reference.

Comment: `$eq: [15, -1]` is pointless, it **never** can be true.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit its just a placeholder, 15 is the value of `score_min`. But you made a good point that I should make my answer clearer. Thanks!

Comment: @ray it works... thanks for the answer...